# How to change password encryption for the H2 database?

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

I have this config file for my Spring Boot project:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(8);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/registration", "/activate/*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
}
```

I also have data.sql file, but I need to encode these passwords:

```
insert into users (email, username, password, is_enabled)
values ('admin@gmail.com', 'admin', 'admin', true),
       ('user@gmail.com', 'user', 'password', true),
       ('user2@gmail.com', 'user2', 'password', true);

insert into user_role (user_id, roles)
values (100000, 'ADMIN'),
       (100000, 'USER'),
       (100001, 'USER'),
       (100002, 'USER');
```

For the "PostgreSQL" I can set the encoding this way:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pgcrypto;

UPDATE users SET password = crypt(password, gen_salt('bf', 8));
```

But it doesn't work with the H2 database. How to fix it and encode the password?

Comment: This is secure hashing, not encryption.

Answer (score 0):

SQL does not have any **portable** way for this purpose, but some databases have own functions. In H2 you can use [HASH](https://h2database.com/html/functions.html#hash) to generate a hash of password.

```sql
UPDATE USERS SET PASSWORD = HASH('SHA256', PASSWORD, 1000);

SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = ? AND IS_ENABLED AND PASSWORD = HASH('SHA256', ?, 1000);
```

You can also use the [SECURE_RAND](https://h2database.com/html/functions.html#secure_rand) function to generate a salt to concatenate it with a password, but you have to store the salt separately in its own column or in the same column with a separator (or by using the known length of the hash function).

```sql
UPDATE USERS SET PASSWORD = (@S := SECURE_RAND(16)) || HASH('SHA256', @S || PASSWORD, 1000);

SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = 'user'
    AND HASH('SHA256', SUBSTRING(PASSWORD FROM 1 FOR 32) || 'password',  1000)
        = SUBSTRING(PASSWORD FROM 33);
```

You can also write user-defined functions to emulate functions from PostgreSQL.

The more reliable solution will be to use the Java code instead, it will not depend on database that you currently use.

```java
final int keyLength = 256 / 8;
final String algorithm = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256";
final int saltLength = 16;
final int numIterations = 1000;
SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong();
SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
// Encode
String password = "test";
byte[] salt = sr.generateSeed(saltLength);
byte[] encodedPassword = skf
        .generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, numIterations, keyLength * 8))
        .getEncoded();
byte[] passwordHash = Arrays.copyOf(salt, saltLength + keyLength);
System.arraycopy(encodedPassword, 0, passwordHash, saltLength, keyLength);
// Check
String password2 = "test";
salt = Arrays.copyOf(passwordHash, saltLength);
byte[] encodedPassword2 = skf
        .generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(password2.toCharArray(), salt, numIterations, keyLength * 8))
        .getEncoded();
// Always test all bytes to prevent timing attack
int bits = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < keyLength; i++) {
    bits |= passwordHash[i + saltLength] ^ encodedPassword2[i];
}
boolean valid = bits == 0;
```